# ErrorDocument 403 is not accessible by its 403 access deny in Apache

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I implemented a global IP block at `httpd.conf` in my Apache server that shows banned IP the 403 error document, but the 403 error document is not accessible because banned IPs' access is denied again so that they can't see the 403 error document by 403 error. It says `403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Include conf/banlist.conf
    </RequireAll>
    ErrorDocument 403 "/error403.php"
</Directory>

<Location />
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Include conf/banlist.conf
    </RequireAll>
    ErrorDocument 403 "/error403.php"
</Location>
```

This is my access control code in `httpd.conf`. Where should I handle it to allow banned IPs to access the 403 document without disabling the global IP block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow banned IPs to access the 403 error document, You should make a directory and configure it with a different access level. make `errorpages` directory first and implement this code in `httpd.conf`.

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/errorpages">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Location /errorpages>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

also, You need to change `ErrorDocument 403 "/error403.php"` into `ErrorDocument 403 "/errorpages/error403.php"`

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Include conf/banlist.conf
    </RequireAll>
    ErrorDocument 403 "/errorpages/error403.php"
</Directory>

<Location />
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Include conf/banlist.conf
    </RequireAll>
    ErrorDocument 403 "/errorpages/error403.php"
</Location>
```

then they can see the 403 error document, but they are still not allowed to see other pages in your server.